# Trying to run a python program but I keep getting file is not a package error

Tags: python, django

I've got a python program "LoginServiceBase.py"  Defined inside a directory called 'LoginService'.  I've created an __init__.py file that looks like this:

```
  # Import views and other necessary modules                                      
  from .views import LoginView, SignupView
  from .LoginServiceBase import settings                                        
                                                                                  
  # Define package-level variables                                                
  APP_NAME = 'LoginServiceBase'
```

My LoginServiceBase.py uses Django.  I've set up a class inside LoginServiceBase for my Django settings.

When I attempt to run python -m LoginServiceBase, I get the following error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'LoginServiceModule.settings'; 'LoginServiceModule' is not a package

The LoginView and SignupView classes are defined in the same directory and are contained in a file called 'views.py'.

Where is the name 'LoginServiceModule' coming from?  I haven't defined it anywhere.  Is this a required naming convention for Python packages?

Any help appreciated.

```
traceback (most recent call last):   
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
     return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,   
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
     exec(code, run_globals)   
File "/home/bbrelin/src/repos/mednotes/src/Microservices/LoginService/LoginServiceBase.py", line 4, in <module>
     application = get_wsgi_application()   
File "/home/bbrelin/src/repos/mednotes/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
File "/home/bbrelin/src/repos/mednotes/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)   
File "/home/bbrelin/src/repos/mednotes/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __getattr__
     self._setup(name)   
File "/home/bbrelin/src/repos/mednotes/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in _setup
     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
```

Comment: could you please post the complete error trace

Comment: The error trace is really long and exceeds the maximum amount of characters that I can put into a comment....  I will attempt to put the traceback into multiple comments...

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/bbrelin/src/repos/mednotes/src/Microservices/LoginService/LoginServiceBase.py", line 4, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/bbrelin/src/repos/mednotes/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
```

Comment: ```File "/home/bbrelin/src/repos/mednotes/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/home/bbrelin/src/repos/mednotes/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/bbrelin/src/repos/mednotes/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  ```

Comment: There's more, but I'm not sure how useful it is.  It appears to me to be an issue with the Django wsgi_application() method.

Answer (score 0):

you need to point to the correct django settings file before get_wsgi_application() :

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'xyz.settings')
```